# How to merge groups of 10+ lines into 1 line repeatedly, in the same file

Tags: notepad++

I am having .txt file like below mentioned,

```
39063960    
Li D/C11 r..31/181,,-350505 Stra.ugh    
I.
Collins 
29052 Humi Street Center I Hillsdale Dr 
Mineral Point 53565 Tuesday, 07/13/1965
Cynthi 1 umfOrd Pi rk.ski (Sgm) 
Non ri nng
Atttached Si ngle -unii t   
95279148100-0805    
Debt
con. di a, on MAI Ad.enes 11440300  
347 3.62
107413.54   
Secured Laon 1353410.568 4E11388.6

LANCASTER POLLARD MORTGAGE COM rimbi rt 
fames
zi ngeser   
U T. R. No.ARSWf34/7U1-49899
N. I . N.La_351 g0b84-Dvb67- 281985 Articled Clerk -  
Legai Assistarrt Yes MISSOURI HOUSING DEV COMM Bank  
Of America Good 
39063965    
L iD/C11 r ._31#81_14-113096 muhlbauer
0..11 ina (Sma  
31299 Tiaani 91 iy Pry Rd. Grosvenor
Place   
Naval Supply Center 92132 Tuesday. 07/221975
631 ly fi el d  
j. car Ishaf fi r Moor rni n    
Attached
Mul t i - unit 95279148100-0828 
Debt consolidation FHLE
Advacen 
4400000 
420 4.48 42240 Secured
Loan 532224 1971200 
OPPENHEIMER MULTIFAMILY HAG
o bani on   
bruce foreman
ii.T.R . No AvsTb3 n74/3msds6,- 57817
M. I. No it La_35ig01,84-Dvb67- 307478 Graft Mosaic Yes  
CENTENNIAL MORTGAGE IN APPLGATE Master Card Goon
39063961    
L iD/CTI r  
351117 yvi nStead
it tyi davis (mcpo 818 03th St W 3, 1 Tg St I Pi 6.di 1 1 y  
Court Grand Rapids 49508 Thursdajy, 01/22/1959
pesternak   
b. n black  
Evnini ng   
SEMI
DETACHED    
95279148100-0812    
Debt consol i da i . n
Fanni ie Mae Mortgage   
13567000    
216 
4.49
253815.96   
Secured Loan 3198081.075 6091583
MBANK NATINONAL ASSOCIATE*  
Passaro 
Neese
D Enright   
U.T.R.No.REXfun02/hg53_213hR- 67973
N I . No4La_3Si g0b84 -D.67-284256 Ca re Ass) 93606 ,  
Home Care Assi sta. ,Home Care Organiser Yes GRADABRIDGE  
REAL ESTATE CAPITA Master Card Good 
39063966    
OD/C-11r ._31.81,-117080 LADBETTER
BOUDRY 29052 8 Hunri Street Center Ki 1 ton High Way, Apt  
wi 11 au ra estates 95945 Tuesday. 07/20/1943
liti chevsky Costello (csm) 
Afttnernnon
Manable dwellings 95279148100-0030  
Debt
consoli dation Fenn i e Mea Mortagege   
1643400 
476
3.88 12056.2    
Secured boon 151308 . 1624.
637639.2    
PRI4t.iDENTAL HD01003 PAIGE ASSOC
Ter.ce  
Raymond Bossem
U. T. R .No kbYcKni F73_wv57,11414 N.I.NORLA,Sdfd F- 
y7-61.293   
Dorec tor   
Yes 
NEW MEXICO t41G FIN
AUTHORITY   
Bank Of America 
Good
```

I want these separate lines to be merged with a single line like below,

```
39063960        Li D/C11 r..31/181,,-350505 Stra.ugh        I.  Collins     29052 Humi Street Center I Hillsdale Dr     Mineral Point 53565 Tuesday, 07/13/1965 Cynthi 1 umfOrd Pi rk.ski (Sgm)     Non ri nng  Atttached Si ngle -unii t       95279148100-0805        Debt    con. di a, on MAI Ad.enes 11440300      347 3.62    107413.54       Secured Laon 1353410.568 4E11388.6          LANCASTER POLLARD MORTGAGE COM rimbi rt     fames   zi ngeser       U T. R. No.ARSWf34/7U1-49899    N. I . N.La_351 g0b84-Dvb67- 281985 Articled Clerk -    Legai Assistarrt Yes MISSOURI HOUSING DEV COMM Bank     Of America Good     

39063965        L iD/C11 r ._31#81_14-113096 muhlbauer  0..11 ina (Sma      31299 Tiaani 91 iy Pry Rd. Grosvenor    Place       Naval Supply Center 92132 Tuesday. 07/221975    631 ly fi el d      j. car Ishaf fi r Moor rni n        Attached    Mul t i - unit 95279148100-0828     Debt consolidation FHLE Advacen     4400000     420 4.48 42240 Secured  Loan 532224 1971200     OPPENHEIMER MULTIFAMILY HAG o bani on       bruce foreman   ii.T.R . No AvsTb3 n74/3msds6,- 57817   M. I. No it La_35ig01,84-Dvb67- 307478 Graft Mosaic Yes     CENTENNIAL MORTGAGE IN APPLGATE Master Card Goon    

39063961        L iD/CTI r      351117 yvi nStead   it tyi davis (mcpo 818 03th St W 3, 1 Tg St I Pi 6.di 1 1 y     Court Grand Rapids 49508 Thursdajy, 01/22/1959  pesternak       b. n black      Evnini ng       SEMI    DETACHED        95279148100-0812        Debt consol i da i . n  Fanni ie Mae Mortgage       13567000        216     4.49    253815.96       Secured Loan 3198081.075 6091583    MBANK NATINONAL ASSOCIATE*      Passaro     Neese   D Enright       U.T.R.No.REXfun02/hg53_213hR- 67973 N I . No4La_3Si g0b84 -D.67-284256 Ca re Ass) 93606 ,   Home Care Assi sta. ,Home Care Organiser Yes GRADABRIDGE    REAL ESTATE CAPITA Master Card Good     

39063966        OD/C-11r ._31.81,-117080 LADBETTER  BOUDRY 29052 8 Hunri Street Center Ki 1 ton High Way, Apt   wi 11 au ra estates 95945 Tuesday. 07/20/1943   liti chevsky Costello (csm)     Afttnernnon Manable dwellings 95279148100-0030      Debt    consoli dation Fenn i e Mea Mortagege       1643400     476 3.88 12056.2        Secured boon 151308 . 1624. 637639.2        PRI4t.iDENTAL HD01003 PAIGE ASSOC   Ter.ce      Raymond Bossem  U. T. R .No kbYcKni F73_wv57,11414 N.I.NORLA,Sdfd F-    y7-61.293       Dorec tor       Yes     NEW MEXICO t41G FIN AUTHORITY       Bank Of America     Good
```

Comment: Unless this is something that you will do regularly, it will be quicker to do it manually if you only need to do it once.

Comment: Have you sufficiently anonimysed your data? I (sort of) see names, date of births, credit card and load/mortgage data, etc.

Answer (score 0):

1. open the file in Notepad++
2. hit Ctrl+H or menu item Search/Replace
3. in "search mode" at the bottom left, tick "Extended"
4. in "Find what" enter `\r` and leave "Replace with" blank
5. click "Replace all"

That should do it. Note that in step 4,`\r` works on Windows. If you have any problems, try various combinations of `\r` and `\n` e.g `\r\n`. Just type the two characters `\` and `r` for `\r` - it's not any special key combination in this case.

What this is doing is replacing the "end of line" Character(s) by nothing, to make one big line.

Different operating systems have different [line endings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) , although really only Windows and Linux are popular nowadays.

Please let us know if this works, as it will help others in future.

Comment: They don't want a single line. They want to merge only some of them.

Comment: I see. I didn't quite understand that from the question's title, so I edited it; I hope that you don't mind. So, what is the separator? A blank line? Something else? Your title says "10+ lines", so we can't count them. How do we know when it's the end of a "section" which should be combined into a single line? Please don't answer here, but update your question for all to see.

Comment: This is not my question.

Comment: Then please change the title back. Sorry about that (+1). Can you please explain what your question is? It seems that you want to make groups of 10+ lines into a single line, many times in one file. Is that correct? Since you say 10+, we can't count the lines. So, how do we know when it is the end of one group and the beginning of a new one?

Comment: **I am not** OP.

Comment: Lolx! Oh, ***now*** I understand. Sorry (+1), I have been in & out of meetings and didn't notice that. What do you think - has the OP defined the problem, or are there gaps?

Comment: Looking at expected result, it seems they want to group lines from the ones that begin with some digits like `39063960` until the next similar line.

Comment: I came to that conclustion too (+1).  Perhaps  @Anand could update his question to explain that?

Answer (score 0):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `\R(?!390\d{5}\h*$)`
- Replace with: `\t`     # or whatever spaces you want
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
\R          # any kind of linebreak (ie. \r, \n, \r\n)
(?!         # start negative lookahead, zero length assertion that make sure we haven't after
    390     # 390
    \d{5}   # 5 digits
    \h*     # 0 or more horizontal spaces
    $       # end of line
)           # end lookahead
```

**Replacement:**

```
\t          # a tabulation, you may replace with what you want
```

**Result for given example:**

```
39063960        Li D/C11 r..31/181,,-350505 Stra.ugh        I.  Collins     29052 Humi Street Center I Hillsdale Dr     Mineral Point 53565 Tuesday, 07/13/1965 Cynthi 1 umfOrd Pi rk.ski (Sgm)     Non ri nng  Atttached Si ngle -unii t       95279148100-0805        Debt    con. di a, on MAI Ad.enes 11440300      347 3.62    107413.54       Secured Laon 1353410.568 4E11388.6      LANCASTER POLLARD MORTGAGE COM rimbi rt     fames   zi ngeser       U T. R. No.ARSWf34/7U1-49899    N. I . N.La_351 g0b84-Dvb67- 281985 Articled Clerk -    Legai Assistarrt Yes MISSOURI HOUSING DEV COMM Bank     Of America Good 
39063965        L iD/C11 r ._31#81_14-113096 muhlbauer  0..11 ina (Sma      31299 Tiaani 91 iy Pry Rd. Grosvenor    Place       Naval Supply Center 92132 Tuesday. 07/221975    631 ly fi el d      j. car Ishaf fi r Moor rni n        Attached    Mul t i - unit 95279148100-0828     Debt consolidation FHLE Advacen     4400000     420 4.48 42240 Secured  Loan 532224 1971200     OPPENHEIMER MULTIFAMILY HAG o bani on       bruce foreman   ii.T.R . No AvsTb3 n74/3msds6,- 57817   M. I. No it La_35ig01,84-Dvb67- 307478 Graft Mosaic Yes     CENTENNIAL MORTGAGE IN APPLGATE Master Card Goon
39063961        L iD/CTI r      351117 yvi nStead   it tyi davis (mcpo 818 03th St W 3, 1 Tg St I Pi 6.di 1 1 y     Court Grand Rapids 49508 Thursdajy, 01/22/1959  pesternak       b. n black      Evnini ng       SEMI    DETACHED        95279148100-0812        Debt consol i da i . n  Fanni ie Mae Mortgage       13567000        216     4.49    253815.96       Secured Loan 3198081.075 6091583    MBANK NATINONAL ASSOCIATE*      Passaro     Neese   D Enright       U.T.R.No.REXfun02/hg53_213hR- 67973 N I . No4La_3Si g0b84 -D.67-284256 Ca re Ass) 93606 ,   Home Care Assi sta. ,Home Care Organiser Yes GRADABRIDGE    REAL ESTATE CAPITA Master Card Good 
39063966        OD/C-11r ._31.81,-117080 LADBETTER  BOUDRY 29052 8 Hunri Street Center Ki 1 ton High Way, Apt   wi 11 au ra estates 95945 Tuesday. 07/20/1943   liti chevsky Costello (csm)     Afttnernnon Manable dwellings 95279148100-0030      Debt    consoli dation Fenn i e Mea Mortagege       1643400     476 3.88 12056.2        Secured boon 151308 . 1624. 637639.2        PRI4t.iDENTAL HD01003 PAIGE ASSOC   Ter.ce      Raymond Bossem  U. T. R .No kbYcKni F73_wv57,11414 N.I.NORLA,Sdfd F-    y7-61.293       Dorec tor       Yes     NEW MEXICO t41G FIN AUTHORITY       Bank Of America     Good
```